# multiple css expression IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-expressions

I want to apply drop shadow filter only if the input type is Checkbox.
Following is working

```
input {     
    filter: expression("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100)");
}
```

However I want to include this.type=='checkbox' in it. Some thing like this

```
input {
    filter: expression(this.type=='checkbox' ? "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100)":"");
}
```

This does not work.

Comment: Are these not deprecated, and discontinued in IE8?

Comment: It works for me in IE8, With or Without comparability mode set.

Answer (score 6):

[You should only use `expression` if there is *no other choice*.](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#AvoidCSSExpressions)

Try this instead:

```
input[type="checkbox"] { 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

This is using the [attribute selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector).

You also said you're trying to apply a drop shadow - you'll have to change that `Alpha` filter to the `DropShadow` one.

Comment: Unfortunately we are not using doctype to be able to use attribute selector of css.

Comment: Ah. Quirks Mode is a problem. I'll have a think and see if I can come up with an alternative, or a way to fix your original snippet.